# Issue with <select> items not functioning correctly on Raspberry Pi Zero 2W (Flask, Python, JavaScript, HTML)

Tags: javascript, flask, raspberry-pi

I am facing an issue with the functionality of  items in an HTML web application, which is a mix of Flask, Python, JavaScript, and HTML. The problem occurs specifically when accessing the application through a Raspberry Pi Zero 2W device.

On the Raspberry Pi Zero 2W, the  elements fail to expand or display any options when clicked on. I have tested the application on different browsers on the Raspberry Pi, but the issue persists consistently.
[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp8Go.png)
[regular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk9XZ.png)
If anyone has encountered a similar issue with  items on a Raspberry Pi Zero 2W, particularly within a web application built with Flask, Python, JavaScript, and HTML, I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions. Thank you!

To resolve this problem, I have already tried updating the browser, clearing the cache, and adjusting the display settings on the Raspberry Pi, but none of these attempts have been successful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm quite confident that this issue is not caused by the code itself because every occurrence of the select element tag is experiencing the same problem.